# Use ajax to call a jsp page and get data as json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I am new to jsp and json, I want to call a jsp page by ajax when click a button. And I hope those data received from jsp can be in JSON (for further use)

index.html:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://dpext.osdp06.ccgo.hksarg:9443/itapp/app3/app3.jsp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        "X-OpenAM-Username": uid,
        "X-OpenAM-Password": password
    },
    success: function(Jdata) {
        alert("h");
    }
});
```

jspp.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>

 <%String id=request.getHeader("uid");%> 
 <%String cn=request.getHeader("cn");%> 
 <%String sn=request.getHeader("sn");%> 
 <%String employ=request.getHeader("employType");%>
```

But after I do that, I return 500 server error. I know its stunk by the .jsp, but I don't know how to turn request.getHeader("xx") in to a variable and put it into json.

Further, I am not really sure do my case need to use json?

Comment: You should return the data from `Servlet` instead of jsp..make a call to `Servlet` in ajax `url` and convert the data to `Json` in java using `Gson` API and send it..

Comment: I have manually built Json before... my advice is to use Gson as @Mr.Chowdary suggests.  It is a nice and simple API.